# How do you write a method which takes 2 int arguments and multiplies them together and then multiplies result by a separate variable

Tags: java, methods

I Am trying to write a method to help calculate the cost of the pipes needed to fix a plumbing job. The method should take the length of the pipe and number of pipe and multiply them together (Length X No of Pipe) and then multiply this by the standard rate. (I have declared the rate variable in a different class)

so the end formula is:

((length x No of Pipe) x Rate)

I have got this so far but i cannot get the correct the result to display. I am running into countless errors such:

Possible loss of precision
not a statement

Any help on this would be great!

```
public class pipingCost {

  int length;
  int pipes;

  public pipingCost()
  {
     this.length = 0;
     this.pipes = 0;

  }

  public void pipingCost(int length, int pipe)
  {
     int pipingCost = rate * (length * pipe);
  } }
```

Comment: add to your class attribute `private static final rate = 234234234;`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia while that would work the OP mentioned the rates are in another class. He would need to pass in the rates or pass in reference to that class here.

Comment: ok, so just declare it as public static final in the other class and use it with OtherClassName.rate

Comment: @locus2k I have added that in but i am now getting an error on the line ```int pipingCost = rate * (width * pipe);``` The error i am getting is "possible loss of precision, requires: int; found double" I'm very lost on where i how a double has come up when i have declared length and pipe as int? the price is a double? have i missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to get the rate from other class (e.g with a constractor parameter)
Then you assign it to your class variable and you can then use rate variable.

I couln't understand where you get the error but if rate is not integer, you have to decide how to return pipingCost. If you use double, you have to do some type conversation.

Like :

```
double pipingCost = rate * (length*pipe)
```